# Get the min and max value in android studio

Tags: android, math, math-functions

what I am trying to do, is get the minimun and maximun value from some float values I put manually. But I do not know how to do it. any helping coidng would be great. Thank you.
Asume a list of floats
p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9

Comment: pls show your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a List Collection like ArrayList and use the default sorting method provided by the library - Collections.sort(list) and fetch the first and last element

```
List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();
list.add(13.3);
list.add(134.3);     
list.add(1.3);
Collections.sort(list);

float min = list.get(0); //1.3
float max = list.get(list.size-1); //134.3
```

Comment: I get it. Let me try it! Thanks.

Comment: While this gives the correct answer, it is inefficient if the array gets longer. O(n log n) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Add float values in `ArrayList`

```
val simpleArray = arrayOf(55.4, 20.0, 99.99, 1.99, 23.0, 34.2, 88.0, 72.1, 61.2, 43.9)
```

then use these two simple functions like below

```
val largestElement = simpleArray.max()
val smallestElement = simpleArray.min()
```